# Is there any way to diagnose or debug my unity problems?

Tags: unity

Unity is really buggy for me! I mean really buggy. Even while just typing the title of this it shut down and restarted itself. It doesn't always restart itself though.

A little while earlier, Unity just stopped hiding and was constantly overlayed on everything. Covering up back buttons and other options on the left side. I restarted it.

Before that it was having a weird compositing bug where the background was black while using it. I restarted the computer to fix that.

But the biggest issue is the constant crashing. While using it, or even for no reason it just freezes and then crashes.

Now I'm not here to complain for no reason. Because I actually really really like Unity. In fact I've tried Cinnamon and Gnome-Shell and I always come back to Unity. And that should be a testament to it that I still prefer it through all its bugs.

So I'm asking, is there any wikis or log files I can use to diagnose the problem myself. Because I've asked people online to help and everyone seems to be at a loss. Maybe I have some wrong variable set in some configuration file. Or at least find out what's going on. I just want Unity to be stable again like it was when I first installed Ubuntu.

[update]
By the way I was able to find these three errors when running "compiz --replace" from the console.

```
WARN  2012-08-01 13:19:53 unity <unknown>:0 Unable to fetch children: No such interface `org.ayatana.bamf.view' on object at path /org/ayatana/bamf/application1339296950

(compiz:10636): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(compiz:10636): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_remove_internal: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed
```

It segfaults after this. "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
I've tried reinstalling desktop-ubuntu and unity --reset, but it still happens

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it really sounds like you should report a bug in launchpad. Please do.

However, Im pretty sure you can find a lot of unity log info in ~/.xsession-errors.

Try that, and report it to a bug report in launchpad - perhaps it has been reported before?

Good luck!